# Srcset confusion in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, srcset

my image is the same size on all screens. I am trying to use the 'srcset' attribute of the 'img' html tag but it is not working as expected. I'm going through like this.

```
<img style={{ width: 68 , height: 68}} src={image.url} }
                                     srcSet={`
                                     ${image.w120} 120w, 
                                     ${image.w180} 180w,
                                     ${image.w230} 230w, `} /> ..// syntax is because the react
```

But when the browser renders it insists on calculating the width of the screen and not the image.
The proof is that all the 'width's' reported are the borders from which the photo changes. But I didn't want this photo exchange for the screen size, but for the size of what will be rendered in the img tag.

99% of the examples made use media query and I don't need it. In fact, if I have to do some manipulation of proportions in the image, I will not benefit from thinking about layout inside the html but immersed in .css. I just need the image to be a good girl and the browser to call the best that fits what I defined in my css file. Am I crazy, or is this infinitely better than a media query inside the html?

Comment: https://snowball.digital/blog/responsive-images-in-react-with-srcset
Please go through this link @Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :-**

The thing is, With srcset, if you've already got a larger resolution downloaded and cached, it will not swap this out for a smaller one when your viewport shrinks.

**How to test**
So if you want to test this, just make your window smaller and THEN load the page (after clearing the cache / or use incognito mode). You will get the mobile or tablet version. Then by making the window bigger, you'll at some point see your browser switching to higher resolution picture.

```
<img sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 730w,
        (max-width: 1199px) 610w,
        (max-width: 640px) 350w"
 srcset="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo4x.jpg 730w,
         https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg 610w,
         https://www.websiterealizer.com/help/drex_how-to-insert-a-hero-image_custom.png 480w"
 src="/img/blog/reponsive-images.png"
 alt="responsive images">
```

**Method 2 :-**
It works easily.

```
 <picture>
  <source media="(min-width:1200px)" srcset="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo4x.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:640px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:280px)" srcset="https://www.websiterealizer.com/help/drex_how-to-insert-a-hero-image_custom.png">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```